# How to delete a column in a matrix in Julia?

Tags: numpy, matrix, julia

If I had a matrix `M` such that `M = [0 1 2; 3 4 5; 6 7 8]`, how could I delete a specified column. For example, after I deleted the second column `M` would be `[0 2; 3 5; 6 8]`.

In `numpy`, there exists a `numpy.delete` function that does what I ask (deleting along a specific axis), but I am unsure as to what the Julia equivalent is.

Comment: Note that in Numpy np.delete do not really delete the values, it create a new array. The same thing is true in Julia because items have to be contiguously stored somewhere (and views do not supports removing few items, lines or columns)

Comment: Creating a new array as @JérômeRichard suggested and assigning it to `M` would look like `M = M[:,[1,3]]` or for column `k` in general: `M = M[:,[for i=1:ncol if i != k]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it directly with array indexing,

```
julia> M = [0 1 2; 3 4 5; 6 7 8];

julia> M[:, 1:3 .≠ 2]
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  2
 3  5
 6  8
```

note that `≠` is written as `\neq` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> from keyboard.

Or using packages like [InvertedIndices.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/InvertedIndices.jl):

```
julia> using InvertedIndices

julia> M[:, Not(2)]
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  2
 3  5
 6  8
```